# 'At' v. 'in' with respect to using the verb 'stop off'

Tags: prepositions

Here are two sentences:

> We're going to stop off **in** Denver for a couple of days before heading south.
>
> He arrived in Athens on June 21, after stopping off **at** Frankfurt.

My understanding is that in the first sentence the settlement is meant, whereas in the second one only the airport, not the whole city, hence the preposition usage. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct! "At" a city if referring to a transit point (or in certain other specialized contexts like sporting events). "In" for neutrally expressing the city as the location of something.